# .htaccess allow specific subfolder only

Tags: .htaccess, permissions, indexing

I have folder structure

```
/Root
   /folder1
   /folder2
   /folder3
  ...
  /folder100
  ...
  /Share
    /subshare1
    /subshare2
```

What I like to do is allow directory/index browising for subshare 1 with

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
```

but I don't want them to navigate to parent folder (share)

When I use .htaccess for

```
deny from all
```

I can still see **/share** folder but not sub directories?

I can't put **deny from all** in to **/root** because I don't want it impacting the folder1, folder2 etc...

Answer (score -1):

You can set `Options -Indexes` in the parent folder, and that would deny index on them.

---

When Apache reads the `.htaccess` files, it goes by the path (from root inwards), and in order to get to the children one must have access right to all the parents on the way. So when you use `deny from all` on parent, you effectively deny access to the whole sub-tree...

Comment: I don't see how this helps. Can you explain then how to prevent viewing on all folders BUT a specific folder?

Comment: @WebDude0482 perhaps you misread the OP question? He wanted to deny index from anything but subfolders of the parent folder. You do that with Options, not by access control. Which my answer covers. If you need deny any access at all into any part of the tree other than specific folder - now THAT is a completely different question.

Comment: @WebDude0482 i'm not going to add the part that you're implying to original answer because it's going offtopic. But look into [DirectoryMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html) directive for that

Comment: OK, I guess you are correct, I hold subject lines to be of great importance, ".htaccess allow specific subfolder only" which was an issue I had.